# PHP syntax error doesn't show up

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mac-osx

I can't get PHP syntax errors to get displayed on Snow Leopard build in PHP module (5.3.2).

Every other error does show up. I've checked `phpinfo()` and I definitely have `display_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`.

It's really weird. :(

Answer (score 0):

Paste your full /etc/php.ini and we might be able to diagnose the problem, but until then you will be able to view the errors in the Apache log files. Not sure where they are on macosx, but here are some typical locations:
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/statistics/logs/error_log on Plesk servers
/var/log/httpd/error_log
/home/yourname/logs/error_log
Or run from the terminal:
`httpd -S` which will show you the configuration file for that domain, then `grep -i "ErrorLog" that_file`

Comment: found it under /etc/php.ini thats also the location that is phpinfo() is showing. http://pastebin.com/V2F6H0rL